# Find the area of the shaded region on the circle inscribed in the square below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

What is the area of the shaded region, knowing that arc AC is 1/4 of the circumference centered on D[image]

I can't finish??

$GB=\frac{DB}{2} = \frac{a\sqrt2}{2}\\
\triangle ABG:(\frac{a\sqrt2}{2})^2=a^2+(a\sqrt2)^2-2a^2\sqrt2cos\theta \implies cos \theta =\frac{5\sqrt2}{8}\\
DE = acos\theta =\frac{5a\sqrt2}{8}\\\triangle DEG: a^2=EG^2+DE^2 \therefore EG = \frac{a}{4}\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}\\
S\triangle DGH = 2S\triangle DGE = 2. \frac{1}{2}.\frac{5a\sqrt2}{8}.\frac{a}{4}.\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}=\frac{5a^2\sqrt7}{32}\\
S(ACB):S_{ABCD}-S_{sect DAC}=a^2-\frac{\pi a^2}{4}=\frac{a^2(4-\pi)}{4}$

[image]

Comment: If one has access to multivariable calculus then the obvious approach is to parametrize the region of interest using polar coordinates. But presumably this is not the approach you want.

Comment: see answers of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2468453), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4388452) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/892696)

Comment: @achillehui  thanks